# KMM Library to interact with Google Analytics

Tags: kotlin, google-analytics, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm planing to create a **KMM Library** to deal with Google analytics. So we create a single source of truth to add the tags we want to track in either IOS and Android mobile apps.

When a KMM is crated for dealing with libraries like **Google Analytics**, do we need to add in the library ***both versions IOS and Android Google Analytics*** ?

if so, I'd appreciate an example about how to deal with two libraries one in IOS and other in Android to execute it.

just need to confirm this,
thanks.

Comment: It's unfortunate that in https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk there are no analytics for now and there is still much to be implemented

Answer (score 1):

I gave a talk about doing this, and specifically talk about analytics in it.

https://www.droidcon.com/2022/06/28/sdk-design-and-publishing-for-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile/

The website has the wrong title, BTW.

Analytics generally is just a key and a map of values. The simple way to do this is to create an analytics interface in common code, and pass in an implementation on app start from Swift (and also on Android). That way, you don't need to figure out cinterop or anything complex with dependencies and versions.

Comment: thanks, passing the implementation for tracking it it was something i didn't consider, my idea was to have a full library with Analytics and all the keys inside, like a black box. But I'll consider your suggestions